# how to use either with more than three options with the word based on

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I would like to use `either` with `based on` for three options.

> The existing methods are based on either one type, fixed type, or a small set of different types of dependency relationships.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is at [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/either-or-or). Your sentence seems to be correct.

> *From the dictionary*:
>
> ---
>
> either...or (...or)
>
> You must answer **either** yes **or** no.
>
> You can contact us **either** by phone, by email, **or** by letter.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include relevant information from that site here.